# DAO classes have the same @Qualifier

Tags: java, spring

I have the source code of a website.

This website uses spring, and I'am confused about the Injection.

There are some DAO classes, on these DAO with a Qualifier :

```
@Repository("myDao")
@Qualifier("myTransactionManager")
public class MyCategoryDao {

}
```

But there is also another bean with the same name of the Qualifier.

And this bean is a JpaTransactionManager.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.PROXY)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.my.repository")
public class DatabaseConfig {
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "myTransactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager(
    @Named("myEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {

    }
}
```

I don't know why the bean and the DAOs have the same name/Qualifier.

Wouldn't it conflict the others?

Comment: but different types

Answer (score 3):

Spring will check for type first, and if there is any ambiguity, then only it will check for the name specified in @Qualifier. In your case, types of both the beans are different, so that should work fine.

Comment: There are more than 10 DAO classes have this same Qualifier. So, can I remove these Qualifier on the DAOs? These seem to be useless. I'm just afraid the Qualifiers have something to do with the JpaTransactionManager. Thanks.